# Using grml with btrfs

Tags: grub, btrfs

I'm trying to boot an ISO using grml and grub on a BTRFS root. However, after selecting the boot option from the menu grub (or some subsequent loader) fails to find the iso /@/boot/grml/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso : Below is the entry from my grub.cfg

```
  menuentry "Grml Rescue System (ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod btrfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  MYUUID-XXXXX
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root MYUUID-XXXXXX
    fi
    iso_path="/@/boot/grml/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
    export iso_path
    kernelopts="   "
    export kernelopts
    loopback loop "/@/boot/grml/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
    set root=(loop)
    configfile /boot/grub/loopback.cfg
```

}

Why can't I boot the ISO?

Comment: What exactly happens?

Answer (score 1):

The live system on the CD doesn't support btrfs. The solution is: put `/boot` to an ext4 partition.